# Counterexample for approximating a Borel set with intervals and a distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have proven that for a bounded Borel set $B\subseteq R$ and for an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ there exist intervals $(a_1,b_1],...,(a_n,b_n]$ with $\lambda(B\triangle ((a_1,b_1]\cup ... \cup(a_n,b_n])) < \epsilon$

I would now like to find a counterexample, for why this is not true if I substitute $\lambda$ with a measure $\mu_F$, which is the measure induced by a density function $F$. I do not necessarily know whether this is wrong or not, but since I was not able to proof it, I am thinking there must be a counterexample. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is still true. The key is the following lemma, "the absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral." (This is a clever application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma.)

Suppose that $F \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d, \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure. Then for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ so that if $\mu(A) < \delta$, $\int_A F d \lambda< \epsilon$.

So, if you want to approximate $A$ by intervals $I$ with $\int_{A \Delta{I}} F d \lambda < \epsilon$, approximate by intervals so that the Lebesgue measure of the symmetric difference is bounded by $\delta$, and use the above lemma.